# Create Mock Repository for dev environment NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, mongorepository

Currently don't see a way to create a Repository that would return fake data to services at dev level. And the only solutions I've found is trough testing. I want to use a enviroment variable to switch mock data and real mongoose connection. Due to the reason that I'm not allowed to use a database or create a local database in dev enviroment.

// Inject mock repository when is on dev enviroment; and return fake mongoose data to the services when running...

Controler -> Service -> (dev == true): MockRepository ? RealRepository

NOTE: this is not for testing.. is for dev environment.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use a database in the dev environment? I mean, technically this is possible, but it's not a pretty solution and it's going to gunk up your codebase

Comment: the reason is that they wont allow any memory database or a database to be used on dev mode while the app it's in the kubernetes pod. @JayMcDoniel Basically don't want to pay for a database instance. in dev environment.